# Google OAuth 2 authorization not reliable (redirect_uri_mismatch)

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-signin

**Not a duplicate of question #11485271 with a similar title**

I'm trying to implement Google OAuth2 login into my web app, but I ran into a strange and annoying problem. I have registered my OAuth2 application on console.cloud.google.com, and I've added the correct redirect url to the "Authorized redirect URIs" list. However, for some reason, sometimes the redirection works, but other times I get the `redirect_uri_mismatch` error. After ten consecutive attempts, 6 times it worked as expected, and 4 times I got this error code. The pattern seems to be random.

I know for a fact that the redirect urls are set up correctly, because otherwise I would always get the error. I'm using the actual OAuth url in my browser during my attempts to make sure that my application is not the culprit.

Example oauth url: `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=[my_client_id]&redirect_uri=https://example.com/signin-google&scope=openid%20profile%20email&state=[redacted]`

I can literally open this link twice consecutively, and one time it will give me the proper google login dialog, and the second time it gives that damn error. It honestly seems like a bug at Google's end.

What could be causing this problem, and how is it possible that it seemingly occurs randomly? Am I being rate limited?

Comment: Please edit your question include the full error message you are getting a screen shot is fine it should show the redirect uri that your application is sending.   Then screen show what you have set as redirect uris in Google cloud console.     https://example.com/signin-google  Unless you own example.com i dont think this is going to be a valid redirect uri for you.   Finally your authorization code is needed.   This video explains this error message https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QHz1Rs6lZHQ&t=3s

Comment: @DaImTo I replaced some information in the url, including the domain because this is the link of my client's private server and I didn't want to leak it on the internet just in case. I copied the redirect url from the error message into the console, so they are guaranteed to be the exact same url.

Comment: Strangely enough, after waiting a few hours, now I'm unable to reproduce the problem. If I had to guess, I'd say that my settings on the Google console haven't propagated to all the Google servers yet, and some load balancer was pointing me do different servers every time. I don't think there is any other logical explanation to this.